Origin Of POST requests with Invalid/random 16-character paths - is it DDOS?
My web site is receiving some POST requests to invalid paths.  The paths have a slash followed by 16 random characters.  The paths aren't unique in the sense that I see multiple requests to the same invalid path.  They look like (one path on each like below):
/EV4i5JthWMjbaddm
/BLXYUCeCZqR8p_5q
/18GpWjfHLcpim4q0
/hQfSu808tgZPwEBp
/rJVyuxUTnk-H72_Y
/KBbcAkZPe68iCaE0

For the most part, the Content-Length is 19.  The TLS Hash varies, but it's one of a small number of values.
Large number of the requests (but not all) appear to original from PacketHub S.A. which I believe is the origin of NordVPN.  However other requests arrive from regular ISPs like Verizon and Comcast.
My server returns 404 for these which is the correct response.
Does anyone know what this is?

Since you are aware of VPNs, you should realise that the ip addresses you are logging are probably not real.
There are always some sites trying to link to your site with automatically generated links. If they bother you too much, you can mark then in GSE.

What is GSE? Thanks in advance.
